# Append a value in an Array nested in a Dictionary in Swift

Tags: dictionary, syntax, swift, xcode6

I have a strange issue with the following code :

```
var dict = ["KEY" : [1, 2]]

println(dict["KEY"])    // Output is "Optional([1, 2])"
println(dict["KEY"]!)   // Output is "[1, 2]"

dict["KEY"]!.append(3)  // Error : '(String, Array<Int>)' does not have a member named 'append'
dict["KEY"]! += 3       // Error : type 'DictionaryIndex<String, Array<Int>>' does not conform to protocol 'StringLiteralConvertible'
```

My goal is to transform the `dict` variable from `["KEY" : [1, 2]]` to `["KEY" : [1, 2, 3]]`.
I have probably missed something but I don't see what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, from apple docs:

> Conversely, if you assign an array or a dictionary to a constant, that
>   array or dictionary is immutable, and its size and contents cannot be
>   changed.

I think if you assign an array as a value of key within dictionary it goes the same way.

In addition Swift collections are copied whenever they are assigned or passed as a parameter.

If you really want to change array in dict, I guess you may create new array with appended items for example and reassign the value of dict

```
var arrayInit = [1, 2]
var dict = ["KEY" : arrayInit]

//somewhere
var array = dict["KEY"]!
array.append(3)
dict["KEY"] = array;
println(dict["KEY"]!)   // Output is "[1, 2]"
```

Answer (score -1):

That will do it...

```
import Cocoa
import Foundation

var dict = ["KEY" : [1, 2]]

println(dict["KEY"])    // Output is "Optional([1, 2])"
println(dict["KEY"]!)   // Output is "[1, 2]"

var array = dict["KEY"]!
array.append(3)
array += 3

dict["KEY"] = array
```

Comment: if I add a `println(dict)` at the end of your code, we can see that the dict variable is not modified (The output is `[KEY: [1, 2]]`)